# Is it possible to remember the first page's url to use it as a link to go back to on the second page - PHP

Tags: php, url

Say for example I have one page and I click on a link for a next page. Is it possible to then remember the first page's url to use it as a link to go back to on the second page.
I have the following code to get the url of the first page.

```
<?php
    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>
```

I also have a link with the following code on the second page.

```
<a href='<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>'>
```

But it doesn't seem to work, because it gets the url of the page that it's on.

How can I remember or store the url to use it on the second page.

Comment: Would use of the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])` variable help you in this situation? There are caveats in using it but if you just need something simple it might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page 1 save the current URL in a session variable (you can read up on [sessions here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['return_url'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

On page 2 use that in your hyperlink:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<a href='<?php echo $_SESSION['return_url'] ?>'>
```

You'll want to escape the output on page two just in case someone is trying to XSS you.

```
<a href='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['return_url']) ?>'>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first page's link:

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/landingpage?redirect_uri=<?php echo urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>">Link text</a>
```

For the second page's link:

```
<a href="<?php echo urldecode($_GET['redirect_uri']);?>">Link text</a>
```

Alternatively, you can just do this on the second page (no need to use any special HREF for the first link anchor):

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];?>">Link text</a>
```